# Disabling a method - iPhone

Tags: iphone, methods

I want to disable a method from running if my audio clip is playing.

I have `myImage.hidden` working if the `audio.playing` is running, how would I go about disabling a method in the same way?

```
if (audio.playing == YES) {
    // image is hidden
    myImage.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code at the top of your method:

```
if (audio.playing) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. one more thing if you have the time. if I want to disable the same method if the user leaves the view, what would I put in 
the:

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

} 

method? my method is -(void) runAnimation;

Comment: You could use a variable like `disableRunAnimationMethod` and set it to `YES` in your `viewWillDisappear:` method. Then at the top of `runAnimation`, you change the code to `if (audio.playing || disableRunAnimationMethod) {...}`.